# WordPress Formidable Form - Changing a title after form is successfully submitted

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, forms, formidable

I would like the contents of `#contact-title` to change after the form has been successfully submitted. If anyone could help would greatly appreciate it.

```
<p id="contact-title">Feel free to send us a message and we’ll get back to you as soon as we can.</p>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('frmFormComplete', function(event, form, response) {
    var title = $('#contact-title').text('test');
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the form submitted via AJAX? If *not* then JS is not the right thing to use. You will need to change the text the next time the page loads using PHP

Comment: No the form isnt being submitted via AJAX. The formidable docs only show how to do this in JS!

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs where it states that?

Comment: It is only what i have been reading on their website support pages

Comment: this is the page i am working from https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/javascript-examples/javascript-after-form-submit/#kb-perform-action-after-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that if you change your form settings to 'Submit this form with AJAX' then it works.